# How to get the dependent entities (referencing entities) for an User Defined Function (UDF)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a database that has been copied, including stored procedures and some user defined functions.  I'd like to check whether a UDF is being used.  Is there a way to see which stored procedures call the UDF?

Comment: Right-click >> View Dependencies

Comment: Thanks.  However, the Object Dependencies dialog for a UDF function (which I know is called by an SP) does not show any objects that depend on it.  The query by davisdba does show the dependency....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out the referencing entity dependencies for your function or any other database entities by using DMV `dm_sql_referencing_entities`. An example statement is as below.

```
Select 
referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, 
referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
from sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.ufn_MyFunction', 'OBJECT');
```